# Numerical precision problems in R?

Tags: r, gamma-function

I have a problem with the following function in R:

```
test <- function(alpha, beta, n){
  result <- exp(lgamma(alpha) + lgamma(n + beta) - lgamma(alpha + beta + n) - (lgamma(alpha) + lgamma(beta) - lgamma(alpha + beta)))
  return(result)
}
```

Now if you insert the following values:

```
betabinom(-0.03292708, -0.3336882, 10)
```

It should fail and result in a `NaN`. That is because if we implement the exact function in Excel, we would get a result that is not a number. The implementation in Excel is simple, for J32 is a cell for `alpha`, K32 `beta` and L32 for `N`. The implementation of the resulting cell is given below:

```
=EXP(GAMMALN(J32)+GAMMALN(L32+K32)-GAMMALN(J32+K32+L32)-(GAMMALN(J32)+GAMMALN(K32)-GAMMALN(J32+K32)))
```

So this seems to give the correct answer, because the function is only defined for alpha and beta greater than zero and n greater or equal to zero. Therefore I am wondering what is happening here? I have also tried the package Rmpf to increase the numerical accuracy, but that does not seem to do anything.

Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. You might want to reword it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** log(gamma(x)) is defined more generally than you think, or than Excel thinks.  If you want your function not to accept negative values of `alpha` and `beta`, or to return `NaN`, just test manually and return the appropriate values (`if (alpha<0 || beta<0) return(NaN)`).

It's not a numerical accuracy problem, it's a definition issue.  The Gamma function *is* defined for negative real values: `?lgamma` says:

> The gamma function is defined by (Abramowitz and Stegun section 6.1.1, page 255)
>
> Gamma(x) = integral_0^Inf t^(x-1) exp(-t) dt
>
> for all real ‘x’ except zero and negative integers (when ‘NaN’ is returned).

Furthermore, referring to `lgamma` ...

> ... and the natural logarithm of *the absolute value of* the gamma function ...

(emphasis in original)

```
curve(lgamma(x),-1,1)
```

[image]

```
gamma(-0.1)          ## -10.68629
log(gamma(-0.1)+0i)  ## 2.368961+3.141593i
log(abs(gamma(-0.1)) ## 2.368961
lgamma(-0.1)         ## 2.368961
```

[Wolfram Alpha agrees with second calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lgamma[-0.1]).